# Java regular expression and escaping meta characters

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write regexp for matching token embedded between two curly braces. For example if buffer `Hello {World}`, I want to get "World" token out of String. When I use regexp like `\{*\}` eclipse shows a error messages as

> Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are `\b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\`)

Can anyone please help me? I am new to using regular expressions.

Comment: @Rajnikanth: try double \\ istead of single \ for escape sequence

Comment: There is an excellent online tutorial at: [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). A couple hours spent there will pay for itself _many_ times over. Happy regexing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to extract the token from a string such as "{token}" by using a regexp of `{(\w*)}`.
The parentheses () form a capturing group around the zero or more word characters captured by `\w*`.
If the string matches, extract the actual token from the capturing group by calling the group() method on the Matcher class.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{(\\w*)\\}");

Matcher m = p.matcher("{some_interesting_token}");

String token = null;
if (m.matches()) {
 token = m.group();
}
```

Note that token may be an empty string because regex {\w*}" will match "{}". If you want to match on at least one token characters, use {\w+} instead.

Comment: Careful: In JDK6, `\w` still means 7-bit data only. “Fixed in the next release.” :)

Answer (score 5):

Use this code to match string between `{` and `}`

```
String str = "if buffer Hello {World}";
Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("\\{([^}]*)\\}");
Matcher m = pt.matcher(str);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

Comment: Why would you escape a close curly when it’s already inside square brackets?

Comment: That's correct inside square bracket I didn't need to escape it. Fixed it after your comments, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

try this `\\{[\\w]*\\}` in java use double \ for escape characters

Comment: Why would you put brackets around `\w`?

Comment: @tchrist: to look for a pattern

Comment: No, you do not need them. `[\w]` does not mean anything different from `\w`. This just confuses people.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the {} in the Regex. Just to extract everything between braces, the regex is

```
\\{.\\}
```