# pattern matcher

Tags: java, regex

I have the following pattern matcher.

```
 Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("[^a-z][^,.:;]");
```

How do I include the `]` character itself in it ?

Comment: You don't really need to escape it (although you can if you want, doesn't make a difference in practice), but regular expressions consider this case, and have a special way to treat it. Check my answer for an example

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape it.

`\\]`

[See this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768480/java-regular-expression-and-escaping-meta-characters)

Answer (score 5):

`]` is a special character used to denote the end of a [character class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html) so it needs to be escaped:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("[^a-z][^,.:;\\]]");
```

Comment: @Reimeus, it doesn't really need to be escaped. Check my answer for an alternative

Comment: Good point but escaping it means you don't have to remember to have it as the first character in the character class :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using escape character \ like this `\\].`

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to escape it. There is a special rule in Regular Expressions, where if you want the actual `]` character in your list, it has to be the first element on it. And it'll work just fine. Give this code a try:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String texto = "[]hello[]";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[]]+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(texto);
    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard way is the use of `quote` function of the `Pattern` class. This function return the literal pattern String for the specified String.

```
String myLiteralString = Pattern.quote(",.[:;");
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("[^a-z][^" + myLiteralString + "]");
```

This method escape all special characters of the regular expression syntax.